# jRating: How to update the star value via xml or give it a default value via option.

Tags: php, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jRating  a star rating found on 
http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jrating

on that same page,  they have options that you can configure as you pleased. except one that I'm looking for.

I like to have a default value let say 1, 2 or 5 star rating for some images. How can I can do that? I'm using jQuery and ajax or xml to get data from the server and assign it to the option that I couldn't find. I do not know anything about php so their example wasn't helpful at all. any help will be great. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".exemple2").jRating({
            rateMax: 5,
            showRateInfo: false,
            isDisabled:true,
            value: 3,<----------- option like this is not available how can I can do this 
            length : 5 // nb of stars
        });
    });
</scrip>


<!-- basic exemple -->
<div class="exemple">
    <!-- in this exemple, 12 is the average and 1 is the id of the line to update in DB -->
   <div class="exemple2" id="12_1"></div>
    <!-- in this other exemple, 8 is the average and 2 is the id of the line to update     in DB -->
   <div class="exemple2" id="8_2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from the [examples](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/) and the [source](https://github.com/alpixel/jRating/blob/master/jquery/jRating.jquery.js), you need to name the id of the div where you set up your rating component such that it should be something like x_y.
where x is the proportion of rating that you want to give.

For example if you want to have total 5 stars (length = 5) in your system. Examples:

- If you want a default rating of 2.5, then x would be 10 [as 5*(10/20) = 2.5]. The Id of that div could be named as "10_2".
- If you want a rating of 4, then x would be 16 [as 5*(16/20) = 4]. The Id of that div could be named as "16_5".

[The score is calculated from 20. Number of stars is configurable]

You may fetch the data in whichever manner you please to, however, while creating the divs for rating, you will have to follow this naming convention to use this plugin [from what I understand].

Answer (score 0):

It's not an option.  You have to modify jRating.jquery.js

```
        var startWidth = 0;
        if($(this).data('rating')){
            rating = $(this).data('rating');
            rating = parseFloat(rating);
            startWidth = rating/opts.rateMax*widthRatingContainer; // Width of the color Container
            ratingWidth = startWidth;
        }
```

Before

```
average = $('<div>', {
            'class' : 'jRatingAverage',
            css:{
                width: 0,
                top:- starHeight
            }
        }).appendTo($(this)),
```

And change the 0 to startWidth, then set the data-rating attribute to your default.

```
<div id="star_rating" data-rating="3"></div>
```